# access vba Append query results to XML file

Tags: xml, vba, export

I have an xlsx file that has some headings in it that goes down as far as row 6. 
I need to get the results of a query and put them into the file in row 7 onwards.
Im not sure do i append or export the query results.

```
Const acExportQuery = 1
Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "\HealthyImmunity Contact Manager - V1.53.adp"
objAccess.ExportXML acAppendData, "c:\scripts\testOrder.xlsx", "col_USbatchOrders"
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example code which you can trigger from excel.. add it to workbook_open even in excel and it should import the query execution result from database

```
 Sub GetData()

 Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection

 Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

 Dim sQRY As String

 Dim strFilePath As String

 strFilePath = "\HealthyImmunity Contact Manager - V1.53.adp"   
 Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
 Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
 Sheet1.Range("DataRange").ClearContents
 cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & strFilePath & ";"
 sQRY = "SELECT tblData.* FROM tblData"
 rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
 rs.Open sQRY, cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Sheet1.Range("B2").CopyFromRecordset rs
 rs.Close
 Set rs = Nothing
 cnn.Close
 Set cnn = Nothing
 Exit Sub
```

End Sub

Comment: Thanks for the help, Im actually running ms access so I don't know how to get it working exactly. Anyone got any examples similiar to my original code?

Comment: In this piece of code instead of trying to append data from access to excel we are fetching the information from database using ADODB connection. This is much more easier since you can customize how the data can be populated in your excel sheet.

Comment: Its giving me errors when i run it. Application.ScreenUpdating = False - Method or data memmber not found. The order of the results from the query already match up to the right order that i want in xml.